# How to disable all option second select box that can be less than to first select box selected option?

Tags: php, jquery

I have requirement to get date between particular years so I have put two dropdown “from year” and “to Year” but I want to make validation for that “to dropdown” value must be great than “form dropdown”

Below is my html code

```
<div class="graph-filter">

<label>From</label>
<select onchange="change_data_year();" id="from_data_year" name="from_data_year" class="graph-select">
    <option selected="" value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>                                                                  
</select>

<label>To</label>
<select id="to_data_year" name="to_data_year" class="graph-select">
    <option selected="" value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>                                                                  
</select> 

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/zmrgp99f/

Comment: @Mukund but your code is working, the alert appears correctly its not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 function change_data_year(){

    $('#to_data_year option').prop('disabled',false);
    var from_data_year=$('#from_data_year').val();
    var to_data_year=$('#to_data_year').val();

    $('#to_data_year option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() < from_data_year;
     }).prop('disabled', true);

 }
```

I hope that is like you need it.